# AsyncTask with android:noHistory="true"

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-activity, android-asynctask

In `AndroidManifest.xml` file, I have `android:noHistory="true"` attribute in an `activity`. In that `activity`, I have an `AsyncTask` performing a long running task. Will the `AsyncTask` continue to run when I move on to another `activity`? Or will opening another `activity` cause the `AsyncTask` to stop?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it will continue until it is done. But be careful that you are not doing something with the activity in the onPostExecute.

Comment: as it would cause an exception : you can't manipulate the widgets of a view that is not attached anymore to the screen.

Comment: From my understanding, using android:noHistory="true" will cause the current activity to end when another activity is started. Will the AsyncTask end with the activity? Or will it carry on even after the end of the activity?

Comment: Because the AsyncTask is another thread, it will carry on. Cause if you call finish(), you also stop the activity.

Answer (score 0):

It will continue because it's running in a thread of its own, but it involves some potential issues regarding updating the UI and handling screen rotations.

I would recommend that you start a `Service` instead and run your `AsyncTask` or `Loader` in there. Once it's done, you can use the `LocalBroadcastManager` to let any activities know that your `Service` is done and that the UI needs to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

A good option for you would be to use [loaders](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/loaders.html), they offer this kind of task management and will cancel the underlying asynctask in case of a rotation or other causes that make an activity disappear.